# Not sure how to fix this Cmd command error?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command, pip

Im on windows 8 and i have installed the latest python,and im going to use sublime text 3 as my ide to create a website using flask.But firstly i needed to install a virtual enviroment using this command pip install virtualenv,and this is the response i recived by cmd.

```
C:\Users\osman_000>pip install virtualenv
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\osman_000>
```

Please can someone help if you know how to fix this,as im not excatly sure what do from here thanks.

Comment: You need to give the absolute path for pip.exe. For example mine is C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe

Or you could run the command from that directory.

Comment: How do I locate that as I'm not sure where it is

Comment: It depends on where you installed Python. I think the default directory is C:\Python27

Comment: You can find out where you installed python by using `import sys`

`print(sys.executable)`

Comment: I opened up the scripts location but I did uninstall p2 with and already have p3

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows, `pip` is stored in the Python scripts folder, e.g. "`C:\Python27\Scripts`".

**How to run `pip`?**

- Open a Command line by pressing `[WIN]+R` and typing `cmd.exe`.
- Then navigate tho the Scrips folder of your Python installation by typing `cd "C:\Python27\Scripts"` (Or where else you've installed Python) into the command line.
- To run `pip` now type `pip.exe` into the command line. This should print a help message.
- If so, you can use `pip install package_name` to install a Python package.

**What I recommend:**

Navigating to the Scripts folder every time is very annoying, so you can tell Windows where your `pip.exe` is stored.

- Open the control panel, search for "environment variables" and choose edit environment variables.
- When a little window is opened, press the button "Environment variables" on the bottom.
- Now, double-click the entry "Path", click "New" and enter "`C:\Python27\Scripts`" (If this is your intallation path, see above). Close all windows with clicking "OK", you're done!
- Now opening a commandline and installing through `pip` should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I opened up the path and I have multiple options in the scripts folder do I run any of them

Comment: So I just type the path location into cmd

Comment: In your Scripts folder you should have a file called `pip.exe`. This is the file you want to run. Now you have two options: 1. Always go to the Scripts folder and run that file or 2. Add C:\Python27\Scripts to the windows environment variable PATH

Comment: I have 3 pips 1.pip 2.pip.27 3.pip2 which one do I run and I did uninstall Python 2

Comment: pip is the one you want

Comment: pip.exe is the one which is running with typing `pip` into the cmd

Comment: but you said you have pip, pip.27 and pip3??

Comment: Ok thanks I double clicked on pip but it closed quickly to see what it said

Comment: You have to open the cmd first, the go to the Scripts folder using `cd`, and the you can use `pip install` or whatever

Comment: You have to run it from cmd.

Comment: Thanks but for the record I did uninstall Python 2.7 and have the newest version wil that cause chaoes for future purposes

Comment: You will need to install `virtualenv` using the python 3 pip. It should be in C:\Python34\Scripts. You can add this into your PATH by following linusg's instructions.

Comment: Please can you proceed with code after the following C://Users/osman_000>

Comment: Do it as I wrote in the answer or say what's not clear enough

Comment: It's a bit hard to format with my cmd can repeat the code after the following from start to finish using the default directory

Comment: Huh?? I think it's easier for you to add the Scripts folder to the Path variable, just do it as I wrote in the second part of my answer

Comment: Thanks but there's 2 options under system edit environment variables for your account or edit system environment variables

Comment: choose system environment variables not those for your account

Comment: So like this click on edit system the environment variables click on environment variables on the bottom and I get another  option user variable or system variable and is it edit or new

Comment: click new and enter your python's installation path

Comment: Variable name or value

Comment: first double-click the entry "Path" and then press new not the new below the entries "Path" is in

Comment: If you create a per-user `PATH`, it gets concatenated to the system `PATH`.