# How to install module and package in python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to start with OpenCV with python. I have experience c# and I have knowledge of c++. However, I feel more comfortable with python instead of c++. I installed OpenCV then python 3.4 in visual studio 2015. At the beginning I've received an error numpy, "Module couldn't be found", thankfully, I resolved it. The I got another error cv2 "Module couldn't be found" I asked an [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460015/how-to-import-cv2-in-python-project-visual-studio-2015) yesterday, but I think the question has been left away. Anyways, I'm not complaining, but I still need some help please to stat with OpenCV in python.

Installing python 3.4 **Successful**

Installing numpy      **Successful**

installing matpilotlib **Failed**

[image]

installing cv2 **Failed**

[image]

can anybody help me please thanks a lot.

Comment: Importing != Installing...
You need to install the libraries using `pip` or similar first, before you can import them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very common to install Python packages through `pip` today (recursive acronym for *pip installs packages*). However, this is not that trivial under Windows.

**How to install `matplotlib`:**

Try to open a commandline and type in `pip install matplotlib`. If this does not work, you'll need to do some more work to get `pip` running. I gave a detailed answere here: [Not sure how to fix this Cmd command error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919876/not-sure-how-to-fix-this-cmd-command-error/35919988#35919988).

**How to install OpenCV:**

The Python OpenCV DLL must be made for your version of Python and your system architecture (or, to be more specific, the architecture your Python was compiled for).

- Download OpenCV for your Python version (2/3)
- Try replacing the x64 version with the x86 version
- There are a lot of different binaries here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv. Try to get the one exactly matching your Python version and System architecture and install it via `pip` (cp35 means CPython version 3.5 ect.).

If you have the OpenCV .whl file matching your system configuration, do `pip install file.whl`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's a very great answer, rich of details. That's perfect. I love it. now I've got better understanding, I think that I will resolve it soon. However I need to install freetype png.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you have issues with installing freetype png, you can ask a new question or comment on my answer to notify me :)

Comment: Oh, and you may find these two posts useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829175/pip-install-matplotlib-error-with-virtualenv and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533426/ubuntu-running-pip-install-gives-error-the-following-required-packages-can-no

Comment: @MSTQNB - Sorry for annoying with comments, but if you use the whl file from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib, I bet that the freetype png binary parts are already bundled!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all help, I installed **conda** environment  and it makes my life much easier. I've started with OpenCV tutorial.

Comment: Good luck, and happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install matplotlib using pip (which is already installed on your machine - mentioned in your previous quesiton):

```
pip install matplotlib
```

more info: 
http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using an package such as pythonxy as a start, e.g. from https://python-xy.github.io/ , instead of installing each single package manually.